# Applescript to extract RTF files with hyperlink not working

Tags: applescript, macos-sierra

I am trying to extract both the hyperlinks and the regular text from a folder with 450+ rtf files. Each file has the same structure.

I'm using the following Applescript which works fine and decodes properly the file in the result window.

However I get this error and I am not skilled enough to correct it.

> error "-[NSURL writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7fa6f527c7f0" number -10000

This is the script I found on the internet:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later

use framework "Foundation"

use framework "AppKit"

use scripting additions

set theFolder to choose folder -- choose the folder containing the .rtf files

tell application id "com.apple.finder" -- Finder

    set theFiles to every file of theFolder as alias list

end tell

repeat with aFile in theFiles

    if (aFile as text) ends with ".rtf" then

        set theURL to (current application's NSURL's fileURLWithPath:(POSIX path of aFile))

        set {attString, theError} to (current application's NSAttributedString's alloc()'s initWithURL:theURL options:(missing value) documentAttributes:(missing value) |error|:(reference))

        -- get elngth so we can start from the end
        set start to (attString's |length|()) - 1

        -- make plain string copy to work on
        set theString to attString's |string|()'s mutableCopy()
        repeat
            -- find link

            set {aURL, theRange} to (attString's attribute:(current application's NSLinkAttributeName) atIndex:start effectiveRange:(reference))

            if aURL is not missing value then
                -- get linked text
                set linkText to (theString's substringWithRange:theRange)
                if (aURL's |scheme|()'s isEqualToString:"mailto") then -- email address

                    set newLink to aURL's resourceSpecifier()

                else if (linkText's containsString:"This Site") then -- resource specifier, remove //

                    set newLink to (aURL's resourceSpecifier()'s substringFromIndex:2)

                else -- full URL

                    set newLink to aURL's absoluteString()
                end if

                -- replace link
                (theString's replaceCharactersInRange:theRange withString:newLink)

            end if

            set start to (location of theRange) - 2

            if start < 0 then exit repeat

        end repeat

        set newFile to (theURL's URLByDeletingPathExtension()'s URLByAppendingPathExtension:"text")

        (newFile's writeToURL:theURL atomically:true encoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding) |error|:(missing value))

    end if

end repeat
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the structure of the files practically identical for each of them in the folder:

> This Site (with Hyperlink)
>
> Submission Date
>
> December 12, 2018
>
> Notification Date
>
> October 1, 2019
>
> Event Date
>
> October 25, 2019
>
> Tracking Number
>
> SIFF4964
>
> ```
>     Email  (with Hyperlink)
>
>     Website  (Hyperlink)
> ```

I hope to get a plain text file as such

> Site.com
>
> Submission Date
>
> December 12, 2018
>
> Notification Date
>
> October 1, 2019
>
> Event Date
>
> October 25, 2019
>
> Tracking Number
>
> SIFF4964
>
> address@site.com
>
> site.com

Thanks

Comment: I used double CR in my question to help the readers who will kindly investigate my query. In the Example file the paragraphs don't have double CR at the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry I am a neewbie user, tried to make my question clear. How can I make it better? Shall I just post the script I found and explain the error deleting the original query? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the file content isn't double spaced and your expected return is not supposed to be double spaced, then please remove the double spaceing from the question as it is not an accurate representation of the facts.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly states that `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error` does not belong to `NSURL`.

It's just a typo, you want to write the replaced **string** to disk, not the URL

```
(theString's writeToURL:newFile atomically:true encoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding) |error|:(missing value))
```

PS: Please don't be ungrateful, Shane did a lot of work for you on MacScripter

Comment: Thanks Vadian for your time and interest, I changed the line as you suggested: now the result window displays "true", but the new text files don't appear anywhere. What else can I do to get the script to create a new text file and paste the plain text results?

Comment: I updated the answer, there was a second typo. The URL parameter must be `newFile`. And change the file extension from `text` to `txt`

Comment: I am very sorry if I appear ungrateful ... I am 78 years old and I get easily lost unfortunately. I try always to be polite and thankful to everyone who helps, as Shane and of course yourself.  If my true thankfulness doesn't get through I will try to make it more obvious in the future.